# Icon too blurry in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, blur, android-image, android-jetpack-compose

When I'm trying to display icon with scale I get blurry image. Can't find reason for this because XML icons are scalable and don't have resolution. Do you know how to resolve?

My code:

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_outline_bluetooth_24),
    contentDescription = "",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    alpha = 0.1f,
    modifier = Modifier.scale(6f).padding(end = 10.dp)
)
```

Comment: You have alpha  set to 0.1 f . That might be the reason.

Comment: @ADM tried your advice. Icon still blurry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are `scal`ing the icon. Try `Modifier.width(...)` and `Modifier.height(...)` instead.

It is being stretched. Also, please consider attaching the screenshots if the problem pertains to images or media.

Thanks,